# Type.GetType equivalent in ES6 Reflection

Tags: javascript, reflection, ecmascript-6

I recently read about the Metaprograming improvements of ES6 (Symbols, Reflection, Proxies) and they are really cool indeed, but I had hard time finding how you can create Type instances  programmatically through code like in C# with the help of the Type.GetType(string).

Is there an equivalent option in ES6?

The background is that in an ideal word if I want to use Reflection for calling a constructor on a class I would like to have the type  programmatically as well.

```
function commandFactory(name : string, args : CommandArgs) : Command {
  let commandType = Type.GetType(name); /* theoretically speaking*/
  return Reflect.construct(commandType, [args]);
}
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: can you add some pseuco-code examples of what you want to achieve with reflection in ES6?

Comment: Updated the description with an example.

Comment: to my knowledge there is NO way to get reflection data from a **string** in ES6 you will have to use a contructor function instead. Then you can do `Reflect.construct(constructor, args);` https://ponyfoo.com/articles/es6-reflection-in-depth